# how to show total number of mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count total number of rows with the following code:

```
$countvideo = "SELECT count(id) FROM `videos`";
$countvideo_run = mysqli_query($connect, $countvideo);
if($countvideo_run){
        $countvideo_result = mysql_result($countvideo_run, 0, 'count(id)');
    }
```

but it shows me this error:

> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\task\media\new\adminpanel.php on line 121

how can I count this?

Comment: there's some `i` missing…

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: use mysqli_result(), you missed i

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a `mysqli_` return object with an incompatible `mysql_` function.

```
$countvideo = "SELECT count(id) qty FROM `videos`";
if (($result = mysqli_query($connect, $countvideo)) !== false) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $countvideo_result = $row['qty'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions

```
$countvideo = "SELECT count(id) as `total` FROM `users`";
$countvideo_run = mysqli_query($connect, $countvideo);
if ($countvideo_run) {
    $countvideo_result = $countvideo_run->fetch_object();
    $total = $countvideo_result->total;
}
```

Comment: how can we find it in mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

You used `mysql_result` instead of `mysqli_result`.